# REST API vs API for connecting python back end to react frontend?

Tags: flask

Right now I have a python backend that returns some web-scraped values and gives it to the react frontend using the "regular" api by defining the endpoints using @app.route("/endpoint"). Everything works (the frontend only does GET requests).

Is it worth changing to a REST API using flask_restful and defining the endpoints using api.add_resource or should I stick with the "regular" api?

What are the benefits of switching to flask_restful? As I've understood it REST api is more convenient for third parties that are using it.

Answer (score 0):

`flask-restful` allows you to organize code in a clean and organized form with minimal set-up. With this I mean you can use classes with only up to for class `methods` which are `HTTP methods`.

For Example:

```
class User(Resource):
    def get(self):
       """gets user info"""
        pass
    def post(self):
        """creates user"""
        pass
    def put(self):
        """updates user info"""
        pass
    def delete(self):
        """deletes user info"""
        pass
```